# how Rollbacking Spring declarative transaction when runtime exception been raised(Pure XML)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hi i have a spring config file like follows

```
<bean id="studentServiceProxy"   class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
<property name="transactionManager" ref="hibernateTransactionManager" />
        <property name="target" ref="studentServiceImpl" />
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

i have a dao class and services classes as follows,

```
public class StudentDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements StudentDao {

    public void save(Student student) {
            getSession().save(student);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {
    StudentDao studentDao;  
    public void setStudentDao(StudentDao studentDao) {
        this.studentDao = studentDao;
    }
    public void saveStudent(Student student) {
        studentDao.save(student);
    }
}
```

and i have a controller like

```
public class StudentController implements Controller {
    StudentService studentService = null;
    public void setStudentService(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = null;
        String studentName = request.getParameter("studentName");
        System.out.println("Name:" + studentName);
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setStudentName(studentName);
        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("success");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

i have a not-null constraint on studentname column in database. i am passing null to as a value to property(studentname), consequently org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException been raised an stacktrace is displayed on the jsp.

How can i handle this exception in spring configuration level? Could you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You handle Exceptions in your code, not in your configuration. The `ConstraintViolationException` should not be suppressed even if it was possible - it tells you that your are trying to add inconsistent data to the DB.

You can either catch the `Exception`, or prevent it by checking the values passed to your service.

In the first case, your transaction will be rolled back.

In the second case, as you are handling user input, you can throw an application exception, so the user can retry entering valid data.

Answer (score 0):

Handling internal exceptions not exposed by an API is a bad idea.  The behaviour is up to the owner of the code and can be different for each version as its not a contract.

What you should do is make sure that your data passes the necessary validation BEFORE passing it to the API.  Here your data is already illegal according to the rules you've defined.  So your contract has been broken.

In your case you could run the validation framework on the Student instance and gather all the validation exceptions.  If you have any exceptions you could pass these in a model and redirect to a view informing the user of the issues.